# Integral defined on space of matrices

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have a question regarding how an integral is defined in the following case.
If we consider the real vector space $\mathcal{M}^{m \times n}$ of $m \times n$ matrices equipped with an inner product. Consider a function $f: \mathcal{M}^{m \times n} \rightarrow \mathcal{M}^{m \times n}$. How is the following integral usually defined $$\int_{\mathcal{M}}f(\lambda) d \nu(\lambda)$$

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

As a first approach you can do this component wise. The trouble with this is that usually you want to have a definition which does not depend on the choice of a basis, so this is what you would have to check in this case.

A (very) general definition can be found in several places, e.g. in Rudin's functional analysis, chapter 3, section 'Vector valued integration'. It requires for a function with values in a topological vector space $X$ that its integral commutes with continuous linear maps, i.e. the equation
$$ \Lambda \left(\int_X f d\nu \right) = \int_X \Lambda(f) d\nu$$
has to hold for any $\Lambda \in X^*$. To see that this is well defined have a look at Rudin's book.

Or google 'vector valued integration'.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Do you know an example of how a measure that could be defined on $\mathcal{M}$?

Comment: @JohnJack: Choose any isomorphism (of vector spaces) $\Gamma : \Bbb{R}^{m \cdot n} \to M^{m \times n}$ and then define the measure on $M^{m \times n}$ as the image measure under this map of the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}^{m \cdot n}$.

Comment: @JohnJack: No, I meant it exactly as written. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure.

Comment: @PhoemueX Okay thanks, but you did mean $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$? Do you maybe know of a good source to learn about Young's measure or is [this wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_measure) as good as it gets?

Comment: @JohnJack Since you used the notation $d \nu$ I was under the impression that you already do have a measure. One possible choice would be, in fact, Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ as suggested by PhoemueX, but usally the measure is something which comes more or less naturally with the problem you are working on.

Comment: @Thomas In the notes I am working with it says $\nu$ is gradient Young's measure. So I am just trying to get an idea of what a Young's measure is, the wiki entry is not very clear.

Comment: @JohnJack If you want to know about Young measures you should ask about Young measures instead of asking about the integral of matrix valued functions. Young measures are probably not so easy to grasp by just reading through the wikipedia entry. You should consult the references in that entry. I also do recall that there is a discussion of Young measures in the first volume of Giaquinta, Modica, Soucek, 'Cartesian Currents in the Calculus of variations', that's were I came across them some years ago.